# Proving that two spans are equal

Tags: linear-algebra

How can we prove that $span(A)$ and $span(B)$ are equal? Say we have a set of vectors $A(v_{1}, v_{2})$ and $B(w_{1},w_{2})$, i was thinking to prove that A was contained B and viceversa, but how to do it though? This is where I am lost (note: I can't use Gram-Schmidt process).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can for example prove that $v_i, \ i=1,2$ is a linear combination of $w_1$ and $w_2$ that's there's $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
$$v_i=\alpha w_1+\beta w_2$$so
$$span(A)\subset span(B)$$
and do the same thing for the other inclusion.

Comment: Deserves an upvote! +1

Comment: So we have to do this process both times and check if each system (in this case up to 4 systems) can be solved? Say if we had three vectors in one set, then we would have to the same but for 5 systems of equations?

Everything is pretty clear if you confirm my assumptions.

Comment: @fogvajarash Yes I confirm your assumption.

Comment: Good to see my friends. You and Amy. :-) @SamiBenRomdhane